# What is a servlet's "display-name" for?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

The `<display-name>` element appears to be a valid sub-element of the `<servlet>` element as per the [Servlet 2.5 deployment descriptor XSD](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd). That is, according to Eclipse's XML validator, this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>FooServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bar.servlet.FooServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

is a valid `servlet-mapping`, while this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <random-tag-name>OMGWTFBBQ</random-tag-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bar.servlet.FooServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

is not (which seems reasonable enough).

What's the `display-name` actually used for? I haven't been able to dig up anything informative on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `<servlet-name>` is the canonical, internal name of the servlet, and is used as the key linking things like url-patterns to servlets. `<display-name>` is for use by admin tools and the like.

This perhaps makes more sense when you consider that the XML Schema permits multiple `<display-name>` elements, for various languages, e.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <displayable-name xml:lang="en">My Servlet</displayable-name>
    <displayable-name xml:lang="fr">Ma Servlet</displayable-name>
</servlet>
```

(pardon my Frenglais)

Comment: <display-name xml:lang="de">Mein Servlet</display-name>

Comment: +1 for `Frenglais` and `canonical`. I generally understood what the `<servlet-name>` was for (really wasn't confused about that part), but "canonical" is _the_ word to describe it.

Answer (score 7):

The `servlet-name` is used to refer to the servlet in other tags (like `servlet-mapping`). This could be thought of as the "internal name" of the servlet.  The `display-name` is the "external name" of the servlet - it's what should show up on a management consoles of servlet containers.  Usually, web apps are managed as a unit - they are deployed/undeployed/restarted/etc. as a whole, not managing individual servlets - so there's not a place where you would usually see this display name used.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's used primarily by J2EE web-management consoles, when displaying statistics, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[The optional display-name element specifies the Web application display name, a short name that can be displayed by GUI tools.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShNku.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `<display-name>` element is a child element of `<servlet>`.  These are elements used within web.xml deployment descriptor files.  The  `<display-name>` is optional and allows for a short name to be associated with the servlet which can be potentially read by GUI tools (such as a web browser) to literally display the name of the servlet to the client if that is required.  However, in practice, it is almost never used so can be safely disregarded.