# In Tomcat's web.xml, what is the purpose of display-name?

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to change the path, so that instead of localhost:8080/foo/stuff it is localhost:8080/bar/stuff and I had thought that by changing the display-name value from foo to bar this would happen. But it does not seem to work. So not only am I interested in what display-name does but also how to change from foo to bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805262/what-is-a-servlets-display-name-for

Comment: How are you deploying your WAR file? Where is your `<Context>` element? If it's in `server.xml`, then you need to remove it and do it right.